# How to cache dynamically switched views by ViewModel-First approach using DataTemplates

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

(I am using `GalaSoft.MvvmLight` framework)

I have some views in my `MainWindow.xaml` that I am switching between them dynamically in run-time, by user selection.

These views using the following technique to bind with their corresponding view-model:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
...
<Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:Control1ViewModel}">
            <v:Control1/>
        </DataTemplate>
    ... // Assume there is more then one DataTemplate. Every view has a unique view-model.
</Window.Resources>
...
```

**Control1ViewModel.cs**

```
public class Control1ViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    ...
}
```

The `MainWindow.xaml` using the following technique to switch between the above views:

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
...
<ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentView}"/> // This is were the view appears.
...
```

**MainViewModel.cs**

```
public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    ...
    private ViewModelBase _currentView;
    public ViewModelBase CurrentView
    {
        get { return _currentView; }
        private set
        {
            _currentView = value;
            base.RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentView");
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

For your convenience, I didn't add more controls, just put one (`Control1`) to shorten the question code section. As mentioned above, Assume there is more then one view to switch.

**Everytime** the `CurrentView` property set with a new `ViewModelBase` value (e.g. `Control1ViewModel`), **WPF will construct a new instance of the binded view `DataTemplate` visual tree object**, so the old one will be lost.

That means I cannot cache the views (e.g. `Control1`) while switching between them.

The only solution I had found to my answer was to "hardcode" the View with its ViewModel (using DataContext), but following this solution the bellow happens:

- I am breaking the ViewModel-First approach.
- In order not to break the complete MVVM, I have to change `CurrentView` signature and move it to the code behind of my `MainWindow.xaml`.
- Instead of switching `ViewModelBase` types, I am switching concrete controls.

I would like to know if there is any solution without "hardcoding" the view with view-model, so I can keep the current `ViewModelBase` switch and the ViewModel-First approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have following approach:

1. Instead of taking `ContentControl` take a `ItemsControl`

`<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Views}" SelectedItem="{Binding CurrentView}"/>`

2. Take `ItemsPanel` of the `ItemsControl` as a Grid and for `SelectedItem` set `Z-Index` to 1 and for rest of the Items set `Z-Index` to 0. In this way only one view would be visible at a time which will be over the other views.
3. Take two properties in the `MainViewModel`. `Views` of type `ObservableCollection<ViewModelBase>` and `CurrentView` of type `ViewModelBase` and bind it with the `ItemsControls`'s `ItemsSource` and `SelectedItem` respectively.

Now when you want to open a view, create a ViewModel, add it to Views list and set it a CurrentView. If it is already there in the list, just set it asCurrentView.

Also provide a close button if you want it to be closed forever. i.e. if you will close it, it will be removed from the list and won't be cached.

This would work as if you have different views opened in your window and you can switch between them. And if you want you can close a view.

**Edit:**
See below code:

```
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Views}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <Grid Margin="10,10,0,10">
                        </Grid>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>

                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Opacity" Value="{Binding ZIndex}"/>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.ZIndex" Value="{Binding ZIndex}"/>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ContentControl Content="{Binding}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Here you can see that in your `ViewModel` you will have to have a property `ZIndex`, which will be used to show the current view on the top. So whenever you want to show view, just set `ZIndex` property of `ViewModel` to 1 and reset reset view to 0.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it seems that there is no `SelectedItem` property for `ItemsControl`. This property is only available for `Selector` derived classes. If I understand your answer correct, did you mean a `TabControl`? an example code will be much appreciated.

Comment: Sorry I got confused. Yes you are right, there is not `SelectedItem` property for `ItemsControl`. I have updated my answer and provided `xaml` reference. Yes you can say it is similar to `TabControl`, but not in all manner. Here you can provide a lot more functionality. I am using same structure in one of my project.

Comment: Thank you for providing code to your answer its much more easier to understand. I wrote exactly the code you provided, and implemented the `ZIndex` property inside the `ViewModelBase` so it will be shared between the ViewModels. this is working perfectly! Thank you very much for your answer!